# I need to FIX THIS strategy in Pinescript please

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, pine-script-v4

[Problem n.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agDbe.jpg)Look at the pics!

```
high20= ta.highest(high, 20)[1] //easy line for breakout

short= close[1] and close[2] and close[3] and close[4] <= high20 and close >= high20//rules

plot(high20)
plotshape(short, shape.cross, color=color.orange)
```

QUESTION:

1. How can I tell this strategy to only make an orange cross the first time the breakout occurs and not continue to make x every time the price closes above the high20 (Fixed by @Gu5tavo71)
2. Look at the pics, I need a cross for each passed high.
   But at least four trading sessions must have passed between the present high and the previous one.
   This line doesn't work

*short= close[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agDbe.jpg) and close[2] and close[3] and close[4] <= high20 and close >= high20*

thank you!

Comment: image is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try when condition "*short*", and previously **not** condition "*short*"

something like that:

```
plotshape(short and not short[1], shape.cross, color=color.orange)
```

Comment: Thank you Gu5tavo71!

I have fix with your code! I have another question :D 
I have updated the question by adding the second problem!
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

In this way the code work properly!

plotshape(short and not short[1] and not short[2] and not short [3] and not short [4], shape.cross, color=color.orange)

thank you Gu5tavo71

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
short    = close[1] <= high20 and
           close[2] <= high20 and
           close[3] <= high20 and
           close[4] <= high20 and
           close    >= high20//rules
```

Comment: Mate this code doesn't work, I've already tried! thank you!